# Polymorphed UI elements

Tags: javascript, user-interface, design-patterns, electron

I am building the following app using Javascript and Electron.js. There's video playing at the top, and corresponding data are displayed at the bottom. When the video plays, a marker move along in the charts.

When the use press the Add data button, new data could be imported. Depending on the type of data, different UI chart will be shown.

Which design pattern/architecture should be used to implement this feature? I know that the question is quite vague, but I'm at the designing and planning phase and any advices are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: `Which design pattern/architecture should be used to implement this feature?` which do you think is the right one to use? do you have a shortlist?

Comment: I think that the UIs for data should be polymorphed (all inherited from a base class that has a common interface of getting sync event from the video). Then each type of UI could implement his own transformation from sync event to what is drawn on the screen.

Comment: that sounds like some kind of code is needed